# Powershell account expiration date Add days

Tags: powershell

The code below is part of a larger ps file that creates AD accounts from an imported csv. The section in question would skip the account creation if it already exists. I'm attempting to modify it so that it will add days to the account expiration date if the account already exists.

I'm able to capture the expiration date as a variable, but defining a new var using AddDays errors out.

What would be the best way to get this done?

```
Import-csv "C:\list.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    #Check if user already exists in AD
    if ((Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.username)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
     { 
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $($_.username) already exist in Active Directory."
         Write-host "Adding 90 days to the expiration date for $($_.username)."

         $AccountExpiration = Get-ADUser -Property AccountExpirationDate -Identity $_.username | select AccountExpirationDate
         $AccountExpiration = $AccountExpiration.AddDays(90)

         Set-ADUser -Identity $_.Username -AccountExpirationDate $AccountExpiration 

       return
    }
    }
```

Comment: First, try replacing `select AccountExpirationDate` with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty AccountExpirationDate`. (Without `-ExpandProperty`, you get an object with an `AccountExpirationDate` property instead of the date itself.)

Comment: Perfect. It's working exactly as intended. Thank you.